# Which python3 module should be pipped for `import page`?

Tags: python-3.x

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

I see `import page` is used here. But `page` is a common word, it is hard to find which module should be installed. Which module should I install so that `import page` can be used?

```
$ pip install page
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement page
ERROR: No matching distribution found for page
```

Comment: Presumably it's the `page.py` file below.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down that page and you will see a section called "6.2. Page object classes", which explains to define a `page.py` file with the relevant code.

Same goes for `import elements` and `elements.py`.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can import other .py files by typing `import filename_without_py_extension`. That's how pip works - it simply installs it to a path that is always checked (in addition to `.` and similar). In this case, if you go to [6.2](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-object-classes) of that page, it shows what `page.py` would look like.